# Can't access pipelines devops extension in Azure CLI

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I wanted to play around with Azure CLI managing the pipelines. According to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/pipelines?view=azure-cli-latest), it's a part of the extensions and I will have it installed by executing `az pipelines`.

> This reference is part of the azure-devops extension for the Azure CLI (version 2.30.0 or higher). The extension will automatically install the first time you run an az pipelines command. Learn more about extensions.

My version of CLI is 2.49 and Python 3.10, so I'm good. However, attempting to install the extension fails with a nasty log I don't really understand. Googling around, I learned that I should check what extensions that are available. Running the below command as [suggested in docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/azure-cli-extensions-overview#how-to-find-extensions) produces a long list of items, none of which is *pipelines* nor *devops*.

```
az extension list-available --output table
```

Does it mean that it's not available for my system (for whatever reason that might be)? Or is it called something totally different? Not sure how to approach the problem.

Comment: Error message? output of the `list-available` command?

Comment: @jikuja The actual error message is *An error occurred. Pip failed with status code 1. Use --debug for more information.* and the log if executed with `--debug` is humongous, not applicable for posting here. The output of listing the available is a bunch of packages (or what now that is named), also too large to post. However, the desired extensions are not listed there. Please let me know what more (useful) info I could provide.